# KML why are there 3 parts to a coordinate in a point

Tags: xml, kml

Having looked at http://dagik.org/kml_intro/E/point.html and KML data I can't seem to figure out what the `0` from `135.2, 35.4, 0.` means.

```
<Placemark> 
 <Point>
  <coordinates>
   135.2, 35.4, 0. 
  </coordinates>
 </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: Note that spaces are not allowed in KML tuples.  The third (optional) number is altitude. [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates)

Comment: @geocodezip Very good addition. I've added this to my answer to avoid future confision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#point):

> `<coordinates>`
>
> (required) A single tuple consisting of floating point
>   values for longitude, latitude, and **altitude** (in that order).
>
> ...
>
> Do not include spaces between the three values that describe a coordinate.

Comment: I looked over that page before I posted this and couldn't see that! Thanks